# Hadoop Pig comparing two values and sort them

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, compareto

I'm currently learning the hadoop framework and the pig latin language.
Now I've a problem.

I've got a data-set with the following format:

```
"long a, long b, char c, char d"
```

Now I want to read this data-sets with pig. That's no problem with the load and PigStoarage funktion..

```
bla = load 'data/examples/test' as (a:long, b:long, c:chararray, d:chararray);
```

My next step is, that I want to compare a with b on each line. If a is greater than b it's okay. If b is greater than a, I wan't to switch a with b, so that the higher value is always the first value of my data set...

Is this possible? In Java I can do this with a simple "compareTo"...

sorry for my bad english :-)

Comment: In java you would compare longs with < >, have you tried using them?

Answer (score 2):

```
blb = FOREACH bla GENERATE ((a < b) ? b : a), ((a < b) ? a : b), c, d;
```

This operator in Pig is called [bincond](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#arithmetic). The first one says, if `a` is less than `b`, then output `b`. The second one says, if `a` is less than `b`, then output `a`. Notice that when `a` is greater than `b`, it outputs the opposite.